# [Rails How to specify folders to which I upload files in google drive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api

I use [gem google drive v.2.1.2](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby), and I searched api from [here.](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google_drive/2.1.2/GoogleDrive/Session)

According to this api, I can upload files by following code.

```
session.upload_from_file("/path/to/hoge.txt")
```

In this api, no way to specify a folder to which I can upload my files.

If you know the way to specify a foloder, please tell me.

Comment: you'll need to ask the author/community of the library that you're using

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code from the [Drive documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#inserting_a_file_in_a_folder) that tells you on how to insert a file in a particular folder, specifying the correct ID in the parents property of the file.

```
folder_id = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1TGRPeTVjaWRDY1E'
file_metadata = {
name: 'photo.jpg',
parents: [folder_id]
}
file = drive_service.create_file(file_metadata,
fields: 'id',
upload_source: 'files/photo.jpg',
content_type: 'image/jpeg')
puts "File Id: #{file.id}"
```

For more information, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798141/create-folder-in-google-drive-with-google-drive-ruby-gem) if it can help you.